# C - Piping file from command line to C program, with the use of strtok()

Tags: c, bash, file, strtok

I'm back! I'm looking for some help piping a file from the command line (bash) into a C program, everything works except when I try to tokenize the value every second line, it works for the 2nd, but not the 4th, 6th etc. Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int numExperiments = 0;



void sendToArray(int data[20][10], char *experiments[20]){
    char line[100];
    char line2[100];


    char *temp1;
    int temp;
    int i=0, c=0;
    while(c<20 && strcmp(line, "*** END ***")!=0){
    fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%[^\n]", line);
    scanf("%*c");
        scanf("%[^\n]", line2);
    scanf("%*c");
    temp1=strtok(line2, " ");
        while(i<10 && temp1 !=NULL){

        sscanf(temp1, "%d", &temp);
        data[c][i]=temp;
            temp1=strtok(NULL, " ");
i++;
} 

        experiments[c]=strdup(line);
        c++;

    }
    numExperiments = c-1;

}

void displayAll(int data[20][10], char *experiments[20]){
    int i=0,c=0;

    for(i=0; i<numExperiments; i++){
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s", experiments[i]);
    printf("\n");
        for(c=0;c<10;c++){
            printf("%d ", data[i][c]);

        }
    }
}
void individualAverage(char *name, char *experiments[20], int data[20][10]){
    int i=0, c=0;
    float dataRes=0;
    while( strcmp( name , experiments[i] )!=0 && i<20){
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", experiments[i]);
    for(c=0;c<10;c++){
        dataRes = dataRes+ data[i][c];
    }
    printf("\nAverage is: %f", (dataRes/10));

}

void allAverage(char *experiments[20], int data[20][10]){
    int i=0,a=0;
    float totalAvg=0;
    for(i=0;i<numExperiments;i++){
        for(a=0;a<10;a++)
            totalAvg = totalAvg + data[i][a];
    }
    totalAvg = totalAvg/numExperiments;
    printf("The total average is: %f \n", totalAvg);
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char *experiments[20];
    int data[20][10];

    int b=0;
    char name[100];
    sendToArray(data, experiments);
    fflush(stdin);
    while(b==0){
        int input=0;
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("Data set analysis\n");
        printf("1. Show all the data\n");
        printf("2. Calculate the average for an experiment\n");
        printf("3. Calculate the average across all experiments\n");
        printf("4. QUIT\n");
        printf("Selection: ");
    fflush(stdin);
freopen("/dev/tty", "r", stdin);
        scanf("%d", &input);

        switch (input) {
            case 1:

                    displayAll(data, experiments);

                break;
            case 2:
 fflush(stdin);               
                    printf("\n");                  
 printf("Enter the name of the experiment: ");
                    scanf("%s", name);
                    individualAverage(name, experiments, data);




                break;
            case 3:

                    allAverage(experiments, data);

                break;
            case 4:b=1;;
                break;

            default:
                printf("Oops, something went wrong!\n");
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Also, the individual average function gives me a core dump. Can anyone see why?

The output of dislayAll is:

```
Experiment One
3 10 8 7 3 2 9 7 5 6 
Experiement Two
0 3 2090266759 1011 -1216787076 -1218461544 -1074571312 -1216447140 -1218499016 1074266160 
Control Group
78514226 1815496840 0 0 1 2342 -1216565784 -1216567208 -1216559671 -1218461352
```

Comment: individualAverage: In this function after while loop you should check the value of i, if it is equal to 20 you should return without proceeding further else it will lead to array out of bound read

Comment: Where data comes from is (almost) completely indifferent to the program's behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm not entirely sure what is happening in the program. Something that looks a little bit interesting to me is your reopening stdin. Bash will handle the pipe.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Remove newline characters from end of string */
void strip(char* str)
{
  int len;
  if (str == NULL)
    {
      return;
    }
  len = strlen(str);
  if (str[len - 1] == '\n')
    {
      str[len - 1] = '\0';
    }
  len = strlen(str);
  if (str[len - 1] == '\r')
    {
      str[len - 1] = '\0';
    }
}

int main()
{
    char* line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    int line_num = 0;
    while (getline(&line, &len, stdin) != -1)
    {
        strip(line);
        if (line_num % 2 == 0)
            printf("[%d]: %s\n", line_num, line);
        line_num++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program above reads in words piped in from a file by bash.
I used the following file to test it. You will only see "print line" on the output and I called it words.txt

```
print line
hello world
print line
not this one
print line
secret
```

Then to execute, just use 
    cat words.txt | ./a.out

All the data will get streamed in through stdin right into the program. I hope this helps.